# "TypeError: kinds.map is not a function." React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I'm trying to get data from an API and return it as a 'state' inside a component which is Navbar component but when i try to loop inside the data i get from the API, using 'map' i get an following error

> "TypeError: kinds.map is not a function."

I can console.log the data which is following but can't display in my component this is the data i get from my browser console:

```
 [["1", "Electronic"], ["2", "Clothes"], ["3", "Beauty"], ["4", "Phone Cases"]]
```

My only component is following:

```
function getProductKinds(callBack) {
  var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/products";
  const responseType = 'json';
  const method = "GET";
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open(method, url);

  xhr.onload = () => {
    //console.log(xhr.response, xhr.status);
    callBack(xhr.response, xhr.status);
  };

  xhr.send();
}

function NavbarComponent(props) {
  const [kinds, setKinds] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const myCallBack = (response, status) => {
      console.log("received data: ", response, status);
      if (status === 200) {
        setKinds(response);
        console.log("received data2: ", kinds, status);
      }
    };
    getProductKinds(myCallBack);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
        <NavbarBrand href="/">BRAND</NavbarBrand>
        <Nav className="mx-auto " navbar>
        {kinds.map((kind) => {
            <NavItem>ss</NavItem>;
          })}
        </Nav>
        <NavbarText>Simple Text</NavbarText>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavbarComponent;
```

and the function App is following code:

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import NavbarComponent from './components/navbar';

function App() {

  return (
        <NavbarComponent></NavbarComponent>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Screenshot of my string output on my browser]

Comment: Avoid posting screenshots of the code and Please post your code into the question :)

Comment: It looks like `response` is not an array.

Comment: Response is array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to use `JSON.parse(response).map` to convert that 2D array to array of objects then return the `NavItem` inside the map callback :

```
setKinds(JSON.parse(response).map((curr)=>{
    return {id:curr[0],name:curr[1]}
}))
```

and

```
{kinds.map((kind,index)=>{

   return <NavItem key={index}>{kind.name}</NavItem>
}
```

Comment: Okay, i got this the problem was like i said the response is a string. So i had to change the code in my django-views. Thanks for the help.

Comment: it's a 2d array, and my suggestion above should work

Comment: My good brother. Like i said before i already got the solution and thanks for your effort but it's not an array. It's string so i had to change my API to get an array. I can even send you a typeof(response) screenshot so you can believe me lol. The solution above didn't even work tho.

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch data from API, it takes a little bit of time. But react is not waiting for that process to finish and maybe your kinds array is empty when react is rendering. You should try this.
Instead of

```
{kinds.map((kind) => {
  <NavItem>ss</NavItem>;
})}
```

try this..

```
{kinds && kinds.map((kind) => {
  <NavItem>ss</NavItem>;
})}
```

this should work

Comment: Nope didn't work. It's probably i get my response as a sting not array maybe i should post my django-views too ?

Comment: did you use the 2D array conversion function by @Boussadjra Brahim